laravel maatwebsite subtotal formula showing 0 when I open the excel file but when I apply ctrl+shift+F9 it is showing the total
I am using laravel maatwebsite package to export the excel.
inside that I have used subtotal formula,
but after exporting when I open the file initially it is showing 0 at the last and when I apply ctrl+shift+F9 it is showing data, but I want to show the total at the time of when user opens the file.
here is the code.
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStrictNullComparison;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\RichText\RichText;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\RichText\Run;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromArray;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;

class ProjectPlanningExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize, WithEvents, WithStrictNullComparison
{
    protected $data;
    protected $headers;
    protected $startRow;

    public function __construct(array $data, int $startRow = 1)
    {
        $this->data = $data['data'];
        $this->headers = $data['headers'];
        $this->startRow = $startRow;
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        // info('Data being passed to collection:', $this->data);
        
        // Skip the specified number of rows
        $skippedRows = collect(range(2, $this->startRow))->map(function ($row) {
            return array_fill(0, count($this->headers), null);
        });

        // Concatenate actual data
        $dataWithHeader = $skippedRows->toArray();
        foreach ($this->data as $row) {
            $dataWithHeader[] = $row;
        }

        return new Collection($dataWithHeader);
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return $this->headers;
    }

    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            AfterSheet::class => function (AfterSheet $event) {
                // Get the highest row and column
                $sheet = $event->sheet->getDelegate();
                $highestRow = $event->sheet->getHighestRow();
                $highestColumn = $event->sheet->getHighestColumn();
                
                // Convert the column letter to index
                $highestColumnIndex = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
    
                // Freeze pane
                $event->sheet->freezePane('C1');
                
                // Vertical Merge
                $verticalMergeColumns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K'];
                foreach ($verticalMergeColumns as $column) {
                    $event->sheet->mergeCells($column . '1:' . $column . '3');
                }
    
                // Horizontal Merge
                $months = [
                    'April'     => 'L',
                    'May'       => 'S', 
                    'June'      => 'Z', 
                    'July'      => 'AG',
                    'August'    => 'AN',
                    'September' => 'AU',
                    'October'   => 'BB',
                    'November'  => 'BI',
                    'December'  => 'BP',
                    'January'   => 'BW',
                    'February'  => 'CD',
                    'March'     => 'CK',
                    'Total'     => 'CR' 
                ];
   
                
                foreach ($months as $month => $startColumn) {
                    // Convert the start column to a numeric index
                    $startColumnIndex = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::columnIndexFromString($startColumn);

                    // Calculate the end column index by adding 2
                    if($startColumn == 'CR') {
                        $endColumnIndex = $startColumnIndex + 4;
                    } else {
                        $endColumnIndex = $startColumnIndex + 6;
                    }

                    // Convert the end column index back to the corresponding column letter
                    $endColumn = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::stringFromColumnIndex($endColumnIndex);

                    // Merge cells from the start column to the end column
                    $event->sheet->mergeCells($startColumn . '1:' . $endColumn . '1');
                }
                
                // Set "Plan" and "Actual" and "Billable" headers for each month
                foreach ($months as $startColumn) {
                    $columnLetter = '';

                    // Capture the first and second cells
                    $firstCell = $startColumn;
                    $secondCell = ++$startColumn;
                                
                    // Merge cells for 'Planned'
                    $mergeRange = $firstCell . '2:' . $secondCell . '2';
                    $event->sheet->mergeCells($mergeRange);
                    $event->sheet->setCellValue($firstCell . '2', 'Planned');

                    $event->sheet->setCellValue($firstCell . '3', 'Client');
                    $event->sheet->setCellValue($secondCell . '3', 'PM');
                
                    // Move to the next cells for 'Billable', 'Spent', and 'Invoice'
                    // $event->sheet->setCellValue($startColumn . '2', 'Planned');

                    $columnLetter = ++$startColumn;
                    $event->sheet->mergeCells($columnLetter . '2:' . $columnLetter . '3');
                    $event->sheet->setCellValue($columnLetter . '2', 'Billable');

                    $columnLetter = ++$startColumn;
                    $event->sheet->mergeCells($columnLetter . '2:' . $columnLetter . '3');
                    $event->sheet->setCellValue($columnLetter . '2', 'Spent');

                    $columnLetter = ++$startColumn;
                    $event->sheet->mergeCells($columnLetter . '2:' . $columnLetter . '3');
                    $event->sheet->setCellValue($columnLetter . '2', 'Invoice');

                    if($startColumn != 'CV') {
                        $firstCount = ++$startColumn;
                        $secondCount = ++$startColumn;
                        $mergeRange = $firstCount . '2:' . $secondCount . '2';
                        $event->sheet->mergeCells($mergeRange);
                        $event->sheet->setCellValue($firstCount . '2', 'Count');
    
                        $event->sheet->setCellValue($firstCount . '3', 'Developer');
                        $event->sheet->setCellValue($secondCount . '3', 'Other');
                        
                    }
                }
    
                $event->sheet->setAutoFilter('A3:' . $highestColumn . '3');
                
               // Apply borders to each column dynamically based on the highest row
            //    dd($this->startRow);
                $highestRow = max($event->sheet->getHighestRow(), $this->startRow); // Ensure the highest row is dynamically calculated
                // dd($highestRow);
                $updatedHighestRow = $highestRow + 1;
                for ($colIndex = 1; $colIndex <= $highestColumnIndex; $colIndex++) {
                    // Define the range for the column
                    $columnLetter = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::stringFromColumnIndex($colIndex);
                    $columnRange = $columnLetter . '1:' . $columnLetter . $updatedHighestRow; // Extend to the dynamically calculated highest row
                    // Apply border style to the range
                    $event->sheet->getStyle($columnRange)->applyFromArray([
                        'borders' => [
                            'allBorders' => [
                                'borderStyle' => Border::BORDER_THIN,
                                'color' => ['argb' => '000000'],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ]);
                }
    
                // Apply styles to headers
                $headerCellRange = 'A1:' . $highestColumn . '3';
                $event->sheet->getStyle($headerCellRange)->applyFromArray([
                    'font' => [
                        'bold' => true,
                    ],
                    'fill' => [
                        'fillType' => Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                        'startColor' => [
                            'argb' => 'F9FF33',
                        ],
                    ],
                    'alignment' => [
                        'horizontal' => Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
                        'vertical' => Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER,
                    ]
                ]);
    
                // Apply styles to footer
                // $footerCellRange = 'A' . ($event->sheet->getHighestRow()) . ':' . $highestColumn . ($event->sheet->getHighestRow());
                // $event->sheet->getStyle($footerCellRange)->applyFromArray([
                //     'font' => [
                //         'bold' => true,
                //     ],
                //     'fill' => [
                //         'fillType' => Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                //         'startColor' => [
                //             'argb' => 'F9FF33',
                //         ],
                //     ]
                // ]);
    
                // Make text bold to Project Name column excluding the footer
                $awardedHrsColumn = 'A';
                $highestRow = $event->sheet->getHighestRow();
                $awardedHrsRange = $awardedHrsColumn . '4:' . $awardedHrsColumn . ($highestRow - 1); // Exclude the footer row
                $event->sheet->getStyle($awardedHrsRange)->applyFromArray([
                    'font' => [
                        'bold' => true,
                    ]
                ]);
    
                // Apply color to Awarded Hrs column excluding the footer
                $awardedHrsColumn = 'H';
                $highestRow = $event->sheet->getHighestRow();
                $awardedHrsRange = $awardedHrsColumn . '4:' . $awardedHrsColumn . ($highestRow - 1); // Exclude the footer row
                $event->sheet->getStyle($awardedHrsRange)->applyFromArray([
                    'fill' => [
                        'fillType' => Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                        'startColor' => [
                            'argb' => '99D823',
                        ],
                    ],
                ]);
    
                // Apply color to SOW Hrs column excluding the footer
                $sowHrsColumn = 'I';
                $highestRow = $event->sheet->getHighestRow();
                $sowHrsRange = $sowHrsColumn . '4:' . $sowHrsColumn . ($highestRow - 1); // Exclude the footer row
                $event->sheet->getStyle($sowHrsRange)->applyFromArray([
                    'fill' => [
                        'fillType' => Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                        'startColor' => [
                            'argb' => 'FFD733',
                        ],
                    ],
                ]);
    
                // Apply color to total plan Hrs column excluding the footer
                $awardedHrsColumn = 'CR';
                $highestRow = $event->sheet->getHighestRow();
                $awardedHrsRange = $awardedHrsColumn . '4:' . $awardedHrsColumn . ($highestRow - 1); // Exclude the footer row
                $event->sheet->getStyle($awardedHrsRange)->applyFromArray([
                    'fill' => [
                        'fillType' => Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                        'startColor' => [
                            'argb' => '99D823',
                        ],
                    ]
                ]);

                // Apply color to total plan Hrs column excluding the footer
                $awardedHrsColumn = 'CS';
                $highestRow = $event->sheet->getHighestRow();
                $awardedHrsRange = $awardedHrsColumn . '4:' . $awardedHrsColumn . ($highestRow - 1); // Exclude the footer row
                $event->sheet->getStyle($awardedHrsRange)->applyFromArray([
                    'fill' => [
                        'fillType' => Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                        'startColor' => [
                            'argb' => '99D823',
                        ],
                    ],
                ]);
    
                // Apply color to total actual Hrs column excluding the footer
                $awardedHrsColumn = 'CT';
                $highestRow = $event->sheet->getHighestRow();
                $awardedHrsRange = $awardedHrsColumn . '4:' . $awardedHrsColumn . ($highestRow - 1); // Exclude the footer row
                $event->sheet->getStyle($awardedHrsRange)->applyFromArray([
                    'fill' => [
                        'fillType' => Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                        'startColor' => [
                            'argb' => '99D823',
                        ],
                    ],
                ]);
    
                // Apply color to total Spent Hrs column excluding the footer
                $awardedHrsColumn = 'CU';
                $highestRow = $event->sheet->getHighestRow();
                $awardedHrsRange = $awardedHrsColumn . '4:' . $awardedHrsColumn . ($highestRow - 1); // Exclude the footer row
                $event->sheet->getStyle($awardedHrsRange)->applyFromArray([
                    'fill' => [
                        'fillType' => Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                        'startColor' => [
                            'argb' => '99D823',
                        ],
                    ],
                ]);
    
                // Apply color to total billable Hrs column excluding the footer
                $awardedHrsColumn = 'CV';
                $highestRow = $event->sheet->getHighestRow();
                $awardedHrsRange = $awardedHrsColumn . '4:' . $awardedHrsColumn . ($highestRow - 1); // Exclude the footer row
                $event->sheet->getStyle($awardedHrsRange)->applyFromArray([
                    'fill' => [
                        'fillType' => Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                        'startColor' => [
                            'argb' => '99D823',
                        ],
                    ],
                ]);

                $totalHrsColumn = 'J';
                $highestRow = $event->sheet->getHighestRow();
                $totalHrsRange = $totalHrsColumn . '4:' . $totalHrsColumn . ($highestRow - 1); // Exclude the footer row
                $event->sheet->getStyle($totalHrsRange)->applyFromArray([
                    'fill' => [
                        'fillType' => Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                        'startColor' => [
                            'argb' => '99D823',
                        ],
                    ]
                ]);

                // Main header
                $headerRow = $this->startRow;
    
                // Apply subtotal formulas
                $subtotalColumns = [
                    'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 
                    'Y', 'Z', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH', 'AI', 'AJ', 'AK', 'AL', 
                    'AM', 'AN', 'AO', 'AP', 'AQ', 'AR', 'AS', 'AT', 'AU', 'AV', 'AW', 'AX', 'AY', 'AZ', 
                    'BA', 'BB', 'BC', 'BD', 'BE', 'BF', 'BG', 'BH', 'BI', 'BJ', 'BK', 'BL', 'BM', 'BN', 
                    'BO', 'BP', 'BQ', 'BR', 'BS', 'BT', 'BU', 'BV', 'BW', 'BX', 'BY', 'BZ', 'CA', 'CB', 
                    'CC', 'CD', 'CE', 'CF', 'CG', 'CH', 'CI', 'CJ', 'CK', 'CL', 'CM', 'CN', 'CO', 'CP', 
                    'CQ', 'CR', 'CS', 'CT', 'CU', 'CV'
                ];

                foreach ($subtotalColumns as $column) {
                    $columnRange =  '$' .$column . '3:' . '$' .$column . ($highestRow - 1); // Exclude the footer row
                    $subtotalCell = $column . ($highestRow);
                    $sheet->setCellValue($subtotalCell, '=SUBTOTAL(109,' . $columnRange . ')');
                    $sheet->getStyle($subtotalCell)->applyFromArray([
                        'font' => [
                            'bold' => true,
                        ],
                        'fill' => [
                            'fillType' => Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                            'startColor' => [
                                'argb' => 'F9FF33',
                            ],
                        ],
                        'alignment' => [
                            'horizontal' => Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT,
                        ]
                    ]);
                }

                $projectsColumn = 'A';
                $highestRow = $event->sheet->getHighestRow();
                // dd($highestRow);
                $range = 'A' . $highestRow . ':H' . $highestRow;
                $event->sheet->getStyle($range)->applyFromArray([
                    'font' => [
                        'bold' => true,
                    ],
                    'fill' => [
                        'fillType' => Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                        'startColor' => [
                            'argb' => 'F9FF33',
                        ],
                    ],
                    'alignment' => [
                        'horizontal' => Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT,
                    ]
                ]);
                
                // Add "Total" text to only the A column in the last row
                $event->sheet->setCellValue('A' . $highestRow, 'Total');
            },
        ];
    }
}



the logic of subtotal is here
  foreach ($subtotalColumns as $column) {
                    $columnRange =  '$' .$column . '3:' . '$' .$column . ($highestRow - 1); // Exclude the footer row
                    $subtotalCell = $column . ($highestRow);
                    $sheet->setCellValue($subtotalCell, '=SUBTOTAL(109,' . $columnRange . ')');
                    $sheet->getStyle($subtotalCell)->applyFromArray([
                        'font' => [
                            'bold' => true,
                        ],
                        'fill' => [
                            'fillType' => Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                            'startColor' => [
                                'argb' => 'F9FF33',
                            ],
                        ],
                        'alignment' => [
                            'horizontal' => Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT,
                        ]
                    ]);
                }

